# How do I distinguish between $t$ and $u$ channel?

Tags: special-relativity, scattering, conventions, feynman-diagrams

Here are two fermion-fermion scattering Feynman diagrams for $L_{int} = -g\phi\bar\psi\psi$:

[image]
I'm just wondering how can we define and distinguish between $t$ and $u$ channels. On the Wikipedia page, $t$ and $u$ are defined the other way around.

Also, because the outgoing particles are fermions, do I need to take care of the antisymmetric property? Is there a phase difference between these channels?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where $(1,2)$ or $(3,4)$ are pairs of identical particles, you can't distinguish t- from u-uchannel scattering. You must include both (and any interference) when computing your amplitude.  However, if a conservation law prohibits or suppresses a transformation between one of your inputs and one of your outputs, you can choose to describe your interaction as "all t-channel" and say that the corresponding u-channel process is forbidden.

For example, elastic electron-electron scattering includes both t- and u-channel terms. However, in electron-positron scattering, the momentum transfer in the u-channel would also need to carry two units of charge. So in $e^-e^+\to e^-e^+$, the u-channel is strongly suppressed/forbidden.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By 'interference', do you mean terms like $\tilde M_t^*\tilde M_u$?

Comment: Yes, but that is where my QFT starts to get a little hazy.